# Search one value of dataframe and replace with reference value in another dataframe if it greater than reference value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables in Python pandas df1 and df2.

DataFrame -df1(100 records).

```
No  Customer    Age City    Product  Limit  Company Segment
1   A1  46.49   BANGALORE   Gold     500000.0   C1  Self Employed
2   A2  46.49   CALCUTTA    Silver   100000.0   C2  Salaried_MNC
3   A3  46.49   COCHIN      Platimum 10000.0    C3  Salaried_Pvt
4   A4  46.49   BOMBAY      Platimum 10001.0    C4  Govt
5   A5  46.49   BANGALORE   Platimum 10002.0    C5  Normal Salary
```

df2(2000 records)

```
No: Customer Month      Type        Amount
1   A1       12-Jan-04  JEWELLERY   585470.80
2   A1       3-Jan-04   PETRO       410556.13
3   A1       15-Jan-04  CLOTHES     23740.46
4   A3       25-Jan-04  FOOD        8000.47
5   A3       17-Jan-05  CAMERA      16000.07
```

df1 having having unique entries of customer and credit limit and df2 having multiple transaction records against customers.
now I have to check in df2 against each customers and amount, In df2 if any Customer's transaction Amount is greater than limit of df1 than replace it with Limit value of df1.

In nutshell-- if Customer A1 and Amount in df2 is greater than Limit of customer A1 in df1 than replace value of Amount in df2 with value of limit from df1.

desired output is :

df3:

```
No: Customer Month      Type        Amount
1   A1       12-Jan-04  JEWELLERY   500000.00
2   A1       3-Jan-04   PETRO       410556.13
3   A1       15-Jan-04  CLOTHES     23740.46
4   A3       25-Jan-04  FOOD        8000.47
5   A3       17-Jan-05  CAMERA      10000.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1[['Customer','Limit']], how='left', on='Customer')
df3.loc[df3['Amount']>df3['Limit'], 'Amount'] = df3['Limit']
df3.drop('Limit', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The result:

```
   No: Customer      Month       Type     Amount
0    1       A1  12-Jan-04  JEWELLERY  500000.00
1    2       A1   3-Jan-04      PETRO  410556.13
2    3       A1  15-Jan-04    CLOTHES   23740.46
3    4       A3  25-Jan-04       FOOD    8000.47
4    5       A3  17-Jan-05     CAMERA   10000.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with apply like this:

```
def check_limit(row):
    limit = next(iter(df1.loc[df1['Customer'] == row["Customer"]]["Limit"]),0)
    return min(limit,row["Amount"])

df2["Amount"] = df2.apply(check_limit, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

## Output

```
   No Customer      Month       Type     Amount
0   1       A1  12-Jan-04  JEWELLERY  500000.00
1   2       A1   3-Jan-04      PETRO  410556.13
2   3       A1  15-Jan-04    CLOTHES   23740.46
3   4       A3  25-Jan-04       FOOD    8000.47
4   5       A3  17-Jan-05     CAMERA   10000.00
```